# Why does ejabberdctl not give a response for the check_password command?

Tags: ejabberd

I would like to use the command "ejabberdctl check_password user host password" but it does not respond.  Why is this?  I can use ejabberdctl to register a user, change a password, list users by host, but when I try to use the "check_password" command, there is no response on my command line.  Is there a config setting I must update for this command to show a true or false response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it does not respond. Why is this?

As mentioned in its definition, that command returns a code:

```
$ ejabberdctl help check_password
  Command Name: check_password
  Arguments: user::binary
             host::binary
             password::binary
  Returns: res::rescode
  Tags:  accounts
  Description:  Check if a password is correct
```

How to see the code? One way:

```
$ ejabberdctl check_password user1 localhost mypass11
$ echo $?
0

$ ejabberdctl check_password user1 localhost thisiswrong
$ echo $?
1
```